# Arrange Div elements stacked next to other - Pinterest or Pose style

Tags: jquery, css, html

I would like to implement the style used or followed for images/div arranged next to other in sites like [Pinterest](http://pinterest.com) or [Pose](http://pose.com/discover#posers) no matter what their individual resolution is. I have tried arranging div next to each other like this

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<div class="sameHeightDiv"></div>
<div class="sameHeightDiv"></div>
<div class="differentHeightDiv"></div>
<div class="sameHeightDiv"></div>
<div class="sameHeightDiv"></div>
<div class="sameHeightDiv"></div>
<div class="sameHeightDiv"></div>
<div class="sameHeightDiv"></div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
#mainContainer { width:800px; }
.sameHeightDiv{ float: left; width: 100px; height:190px; } 
.differentHeightDiv { float: left; width: 100px; height:225px; }
```

Which is arranged like

```
1 2 3 4
      5
6 7 8
```

Because 3'rd Div (.differentHeightDiv) height is greater, i know things will work if all heights are equal but i want a solution if its unequal (i mean if each div has different resolutions/aspect ratios) Some one please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/), they do what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ChristianVarga Awesome! Thanks for the quick help. It seems JQuery Mansory is what is used by Pinterest and Pose. So the animation feature also comes with right?

Comment: Pinterest has made jQuery Masonry the new hotness. It does exactly what you are looking for. http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: here is my jquery plugin, i wrote to build the same layout as Pinterest. http://kayschneider.github.com/pinbox/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a nice tutorial on the basic's behind achieving the pinterest layout http://benholland.me/javascript/how-to-build-a-site-that-works-like-pinterest/

Comment: Wow! a tutorial for it is the best, instead of blindly applying JQuery frameworks. Thanks a lot @superlogical

Comment: Yeah it's good to know how it works. But I would suggest using jQuery Masonry or jQuery Isotope as they do have functionality that you will need like adding/removing items from a list dynamically and providing a sort order.

Answer (score 1):

Airbnb has just open sourced [infinity.js](http://airbnb.github.com/infinity/)

> Infinity.js is a UITableView for the web: it speeds up scrolling
>   through long lists and keeps your infinite feeds smooth and stable for
>   your users.
>
> A ListView is a container that moves content in and out of the DOM on
>   the scroll event. ListViews help keep repaint times of expensive pages
>   down (and scrolling smooth) by making sure that there are never too
>   many elements onscreen at a single time. ListViews excel at speeding
>   up long lists of complex HTML elements, where new content is
>   frequently appended to the end and existing content is rarely removed.

[View a demo here](http://airbnb.github.com/infinity/demo-on.html)

Comment: But is this screen-responsive? not at-least with the demo part i guess?